# How to get all value of checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I would like to get all value of checkboxs and store them by id :

```
                var jsonObj = $("[type='checkbox']").map(function(i, o) {
                  return { id : o.id, checked : o.checked  };
                });
                var checkboxs = '';
                if(jsonObj != 0){
                    checkboxs = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
                }else{
                    checkboxs = '' ;
                }
```

output of `checkboxs` variable :
(copy/past output on www.json.parser.online.fr)

```
{"0":{"id":"1","checked":false},"1":{"id":"2","checked":false},"2":{"id":"3","checked":false},"3":{"id":"4","checked":true},"4":{"id":"5","checked":true},"length":5,"prevObject":{"0":{"jQuery18305884705366101428":23},"1":{"jQuery18305884705366101428":31},"2":{"jQuery18305884705366101428":39},"3":{"jQuery18305884705366101428":47},"4":{"jQuery18305884705366101428":55},"length":5,"prevObject":{"0":{"location":{"href":"mysite...","origin":"mysite...","protocol":"http:","username":"","password":"","host":"mysite...","hostname":"mysite...","port":"","pathname":"mysite...","search":"","hash":""},"jQuery18305884705366101428":1},"context":{"location":{"href":"mysite...","origin":"mysite...","protocol":"http:","username":"","password":"","host":"mysite...","hostname":"mysite...","port":"","pathname":"mysite.../subs/14988","search":"","hash":""},"jQuery18305884705366101428":1},"length":1},"context":{"location":{"href":"mysite...","origin":"mysite...","protocol":"http:","username":"","password":"","host":"mysite...","hostname":"mysite...","port":"","pathname":"mysite...","search":"","hash":""},"jQuery18305884705366101428":1},"selector":"[type='checkbox']"},"context":{"location":{"href":"mysite...","origin":"mysite...","protocol":"http:","username":"","password":"","host":"mysite...","hostname":"mysite...","port":"","pathname":"mysite...","search":"","hash":""},"jQuery18305884705366101428":1}}
```

but it returns some values that I don't need them at all !!

```
"length":5,"prevObject":{"0":{"jQuery18305884705366101428":23},"1":{"jQuery18305884705366101428":31},"2":{"jQuery18305884705366101428":39},"3":{"jQuery18305884705366101428":47},"4":{"jQuery18305884705366101428":55},"length":5,"prevObject":{"0":{"location":{"href":"mysite...","origin":"mysite...","protocol":"http:","username":"","password":"","host":"mysite...","hostname":"mysite...","port":"","pathname":"mysite...","search":"","hash":""},"jQuery18305884705366101428":1},"context":{"location":{"href":"mysite...","origin":"mysite...","protocol":"http:","username":"","password":"","host":"mysite...","hostname":"mysite...","port":"","pathname":"mysite.../subs/14988","search":"","hash":""},"jQuery18305884705366101428":1},"length":1},"context":{"location":{"href":"mysite...","origin":"mysite...","protocol":"http:","username":"","password":"","host":"mysite...","hostname":"mysite...","port":"","pathname":"mysite...","search":"","hash":""},"jQuery18305884705366101428":1},"selector":"[type='checkbox']"},"context":{"location":{"href":"mysite...","origin":"mysite...","protocol":"http:","username":"","password":"","host":"mysite...","hostname":"mysite...","port":"","pathname":"mysite...","search":"","hash":""},"jQuery18305884705366101428":1}}
```

Comment: I don't think you're using map correctly http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain the whole working program in a step by step manner. Please see the comments in the below snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  // Step 1: Create a final object, which stores all the values.
  var allChk = {};
  // Step 2: Loop through all the checkboxes.
  $("input:checkbox").each(function () {
    // Step 3: For every checkbox you have, add the index as the id of the checkbox using this.id and give the value, whether it is checked or not using this.checked.
    allChk[this.id] = this.checked;
  });
  // You have filled the allChk object with the necessary information you need.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="checkbox" name="one" id="one" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="two" id="two" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="three" id="three" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is not at all what the question is asking for. He clearly wants to store the ID and the checked boolean flag as JSON.

Comment: If you change `$(this).attr('name')` to `this.id`, and then explain your code, then I will. Right now, it still lacks explanation. "Just use this code" is not acceptable.

Comment: Also, you're offering an alternative solution instead of trying to fix OP's real issue. This is a detraction from the original goal.

Comment: Of course it exists. This is why I don't like newbies using jQuery; they don't understand what it actually does.

Comment: @ndugger Er... Whom you calling newbie?

Comment: I mean no offense, but if you don't understand how jQuery is abstracting `this`, then you create a lot of bloat; ie `$(this).attr('id')` vs `this.id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97118/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-ndugger).

Comment: I have removed my downvote, but next time, instead of coming up with your own solution, please try to address OP's real issue.

Comment: @ndugger No way... I am not using `$(this).attr('id')` at all. I know how it works! `:)` So that's why I had used `this.id`.